Can't Option Boot Mac Pro
Can't Option Boot Mac Pro or boot into Safe Mode.  I get a black screen, no cursor.

Mac Pro (Early 2008)
El Capitan OS X 10.11.6
28 GB RAM
369.06 GB of space on Hard Drive

Using Apple Aluminium keyboard and wired Apple mouse.
Tried Disk Utility, Disk Warrior, resetting PRAM.
Any ideas on what to do next?
Thanks.

When you say you’ve tried Disk Utility and Disk Warrior, how exactly are you doing that if you report being unable to get past a black screen?

I can boot up normally but can't boot using keyboard commands.

What is the “Apple aluminum” keyboard? Is it wired or wireless? (See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_keyboards and please let us know the exact model)

Also what display are you using and how is it attached?

Apple Keyboard (US) (A1243)

BenQ T905 connected to graphics card

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Any updates re: our chat discussion?
